# Iterate and compare values in same map to find largest value and remove other from same map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have

```
Map<Key,Integer> myMap= new HashMap<Key,Integer>();
```

suppose I have elements in map like,

```
 myMap.put(k1,5);
 myMap.put(k2,20);
 myMap.put(k3,10);
 myMap.put(k4,15);
```

What code I should try to iterate and compare values in this map, and I want map element with largest value, also map should contain only that element.

Comment: Finding the largest values(s) in the map is simple, but I have no idea what "remove other from same map"  and "map should contain only that element" means.

Comment: If you only want a single element in the map, why use a map at all?  Why not just store to a regular variable, and only reset that variable when a new value is larger?

Comment: "map should contain only that element" and "remove other from same map" means when I compare two elements for example element1(value = 5) and element2(value = 20), the element which is having small value in this case element1(value = 5) should get removed from map, so that I will compare element2 with next element in map, which is element3(value=10), and so on, in this way I will have only element with largest value remain in map.

Comment: @Magnus..We cant always guarantee a single entry. Say two key have the same value, both the greatest in the map, then the resulting map will have two entries.. Just a thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a wrapper class:

```
public class MyMapWrapper<K, V extends Comparable> {

    private V maximum;
    private K maxKey;
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Comparator<V> comp;

    public MyMapWrapper() {
        this(new Comparator<V>() {

            public int compareTo(V v1, V v2) {
                return (v1 == null) ? ((v2 == null) ? 0 : -1) : v1.compareTo(v2);
            }

        });
    }

    public MyMapWrapper(Comparator<V> comp) {
        if (comp == null) {
            //Comparator should not be null
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator cannot be null!");
        }
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    public V getMaximum() {
        return this.maximum;
    }

    public K getMaximumKey() {
        return this.maxKey;
    }

    public int put(K key, V value) {
        if (value == null) {
            //You don't want null comparables, can either throw an exception or ignore
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No null values allowed!");
        }
        if (this.maximum == null || this.comp.compareTo(this.maximum, value) > 0) {
            this.maximum = value;
            this.maxKey = key;
        }
        return this.map.put(key, value);
    }

    public int remove(K key) {
        V back = this.map.remove(key);
        if (this.maximum.equals(back)) {
            K newKey = null;
            V newMax = null;
            //search map for new maximum
            for (Map.Entry<K, V> ent : this.map.entrySet()) {
                if (this.comp.compareTo(ent.getValue(), newMax) > 0) {
                    newMax = ent.getValue();
                    newKey = ent.getKey();
                }
            }
            this.maximum = newMax;
            this.maxKey = newKey;
        }
        return back;
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return this.map.get(key);
    }

}
```

If other specific methods are needed you can do so, but this will only require a single "map" to be used:

```
MyMapWrapper<String, Integer> example = new MyMapWrapper<>();
example.put("test1", 14);
example.put("test2", 3450);
example.put("test4", -142);
System.out.println(String.format("Max key: %s, Max value: %d", example.getMaximumKey(), example.getMaximum());
//Max key: "test2", Max value: 3450
```

This also allows for custom comparators for values:

```
MyMapWrapper<String, Integer> example = new MyMapWrapper<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {

    public int compareTo(Integer v1, Integer v2) {
        return (v2 == null) ? ((v1 == null) ? 0 : -1) : v2.compareTo(v1);
    }

});
example.put("test1", 14);
example.put("test2", 3450);
example.put("test4", -142);
System.out.println(String.format("Max key: %s, Max value: %d", example.getMaximumKey(), example.getMaximum());
//Max key: "test4", Max value: -142
```

Comment: why not just use Collections.max() on the original Map?

Comment: @bcorso well with this it's essentially a "cache" of the max value, so I suppose it would be more efficient. Offers a little more flexibility in defining your implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to use concurrent hashmap. Try this..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Largest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        myMap.put(1, 5);
        myMap.put(2, 20);
        myMap.put(3, 10);
        myMap.put(4, 15);
        myMap.put(5, 20);

        System.out.println(myMap);

        Map<Integer, Integer> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>(myMap);

        Integer maxKey = concurrentMap.keySet().iterator().next();
        Integer max = myMap.get(maxKey);

        for(Integer key : concurrentMap.keySet()){
            Integer currValue = concurrentMap.get(key);
            if(max > currValue){
                concurrentMap.remove(key);
            } else if(max < currValue) {
                concurrentMap.remove(maxKey);
                max = concurrentMap.get(key);
                maxKey = key;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(concurrentMap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to grab the max `Entry` in the `Map` use `Collections.max` with your defined `Comparator`:

```
Map<Key, Integer> myMap= new HashMap<Key,Integer>();
myMap.put(k1,5);
myMap.put(k2,20);
myMap.put(k3,10);
myMap.put(k4,15);

Entry<Key, Integer> maxEntry = Collections.max(myMap.entrySet(), 
    new Comparator<Entry<Key, Integer>>(){
        @Override public int compare(Entry<Key, Integer> e1, Entry<Key, Integer> e2) {
            return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
        }
    });

// outputs k2=20
System.out.print(maxEntry);
```

If you really want to have a 1 entry map in the end, you can clear the old one away and add `maxEntry`:

```
myMap.clear();
myMap.put(maxEntry.key(), maxEntry.value());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have java 8 you can do it like this:

**CODE**

```
public class MapFiltering {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            myMap.put("k" + j, rnd.nextInt(100));
        }
        System.out.println("BEFORE");
        printMap(myMap);
        filterMap(myMap);
        System.out.println("AFTER");
        printMap(myMap);
    }

    private static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        map.entrySet().stream().forEach((e) -> {
            System.out.println("K=" + e.getKey() + " V=" + e.getValue());
        });
    }

    private static void filterMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> get
                = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max((Comparator<? super Map.Entry<String, Integer>>) new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                    }
                }).get();
        map.clear();
        map.put(get.getKey(), get.getValue());
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
BEFORE
K=k0 V=66
K=k1 V=5
K=k2 V=34
K=k3 V=54
K=k4 V=52
K=k5 V=69
K=k6 V=34
K=k7 V=62
K=k8 V=73
K=k9 V=28
AFTER
K=k8 V=73
```